# Captcha freezes and does nothing

Tags: discussion, bug, captcha

I try to post

The captcha bot (are you a human ?) appears

I guess the right letters

A text field appears on the screen, asking me to cut and paste into another text field.

I do that.

Nothing else happens after that.

Is there another step which I missed in the instructions ?  Is there somewhere else to click ?

Comment: Do you have any extensions that might modify or block JavaScript or third-party resources in your web browser? If so, please try disabling them, including temporarily turning off any ad-blockers.

Comment: Have you tried clicking the submit button again? (Assuming you're still on the original page you posted from - I can't quite remember how SE captcha works).